# custom jquery pagination issue

Tags: jquery, pagination

i saw in web have many type jquery pagination script. those are work and nice too but in my page none will really work i guess. i tried already few but not work. there one reason is i have tabs content and pagination will inside tab content. also my i need make pagination base on content length, so i have no how to do that. then i decide simply make next and back. i am not so pro in jquery. that's why i made something like bellow . it's work but i want to know is there any better or easy way to do this type pagination

**DEMO**   http://jsfiddle.net/cTBTU/

html

```
<ul>
<div id="f1">
  <li><strong>conten one</strong></li>
  <li><strong>content two</strong></li>
  <li><strong>content three</strong></li>
  <a href="#" id="f2active" class="btn">next</a>
  </div>
  <div id="f2">
  <li><strong>content four</strong></li>
  <li><strong>content five</strong></li>
  <li><strong>content six</strong></li>

  <a href="#" id="f1back" class="btn">back</a>
    <a href="#" id="f3active" class="btn">next</a>

  </div>
 <div id="f3"> <li><strong>content seven</strong></li>


  <li><strong>content eight</strong></li>
  <li><strong>content nine</strong></li>
  <a href="#" id="f2back" class="btn">back</a>
    <a href="#" id="f4active" class="btn">next</a>
  </div>
  <div id="f4">
  <li><strong>content ten</strong></li>
  <a href="#" id="f3back" class="btn">back</a>
  </div>
</ul>
```

jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#f2, #f3, #f4").hide();

  $("#f2active").click(function(){
  $("#f1").hide();
  $("#f2").show();
  });

  $("#f3active").click(function(){
  $("#f2").hide();
  $("#f3").show();
  });

  $("#f4active").click(function(){
  $("#f3").hide();
  $("#f4").show();
  });

  $("#f1back").click(function(){
  $("#f2").hide();
  $("#f1").show();
  });

  $("#f2back").click(function(){
  $("#f3").hide();
  $("#f2").show();
  });

  $("#f3back").click(function(){
  $("#f4").hide();
  $("#f3").show();
  });

});
```

Comment: pagination is done for 2 purposes - 1. save real estate, 2. save bandwidth and load content on next/back. what is your use case here?

Comment: my case i have fix height content area. if my content full fill then content area then if i click next then show next content. same next next back back.. just show content in my fixed height

Comment: this might help: http://jsfiddle.net/Seandeburca/fQAuE/3/  There is an issue with clicking on prev or next during animation, would be best to disable the listeners during animate, need to fix

Comment: do you mean the number of li to show could also vary as in to fit the content in the fix height?

Comment: @sdeburca thanks ... its seems work. something like that also good.

Comment: @gp .. no not li number. it will fit with content fix height.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid hardcoding.
You have 2 options:

1. If the content is preloaded, hide all and show a subset. 
   `$('li').hide(); $('li').splice(index, index+lengthToShow).show()`. 
   Check this http://jsfiddle.net/uJQXc/
2. dynamically load the page content from server and show it in the UI.
   `$('#container').load('ajax/content?page=0&size=3')`

Comment: thanks gp. i checked but your one base of li number. i mean for content fix hegiht. li no mater.. i don't have all tabs li . some have div some have p.. but mainly fit on fix height then next next or number what ever